# How do I set a default toolchain in Eclipse C++ / CPP for new projects?

Tags: c++, eclipse, default, toolchain

I would like to have eclipse cpp kepler use the toolchain MingW GCC by default?

When I click File > New > C++ Project, the dialog box displays the following options for Toolchains.

```
Toolchains:
Cross GCC
Cygwin GCC
Microsoft Visual C++
MingW GCC
```

If I do not specify a Toolchain, Eclipse will default to Cross GCC.  If I want to use MingW  GCC, I have to click its name.  I would like Eclipse to default to MingW GCC so I do not have to click it each time.  How would I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to preferences>C/C++>New C/C++ project wizard, then pick your toolchain and click "make toolchain preferred". This will now be the default toolchain on startup.